# android implements runnable not working?

Tags: android

this is a simple code to understand the runnable .I tried but not working . can you guys help me pls this is my code

```
public class Autostart extends activity implements Runnable {
@override 
public void run  (){
System.out.println ("message");
}
}
}
```

this not printing any statements

Comment: are you calling run() ? it doesn't invoke itself automagically

Comment: then how to run automatically

Comment: why and how should it run automatically?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Activity has its own lifecycle. Just override some methods like "onCreate" / onStart / onResume if you want to simply print some message.

Comment: just like a thread .....I want to print the time periodically

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an Activity, you need to write your code inside Activity lifecycle methods. `onCreate()` is called when the Activity is created. So starting your Runnable here would be the correct way to do it.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         System.out.println ("message");    
       }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}
```

Comment: how to use implements runnable ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a Thread object and call start() using that object.

```
 Thread t = new Thread(this);
 t.start();
```

Or Just use Handler

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do Something here
            }
        }, 5000);
```

Comment: how to use implements runnable ?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use below code to print a value after regular interval of time

```
 public void callAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
     timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        Log.e("on print timee", your value);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 1000); // will execute  after  1 sec 
}
```

> Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar solution to Swayam ([android implements runnable not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909781/android-implements-runnable-not-working#36909949)), however another `handler.postDelayed` reference within `run()` was required;

```
public void onCreate(
    ...
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "message");
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            ...
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
    Handler mainThreadhandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    mainThreadhandler.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            // UI work
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Autostart extends activity implements Runnable {
  Thread = thread;
  @override
  public void onCreate() {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
  }
  @override 
  public void run  (){
    System.out.println ("message");
  }
}
```